# How to select parent property value based on child property value from JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting json data from an API call, and need to read specific values from the data.

The following is a simplified version of the json:

```
  {
     "Modules":[
        {
           "ModuleId":370,
           "Title":"Getting Oriented",
           "Modules":[
              {
                 "ModuleId":378,
                 "Title":"Artifacts",
                 "Modules":[

                 ],
                 "Topics":[
                    {
                       "TopicId":379
                    },
                    {
                       "TopicId":380                     
                    },
                    {
                       "TopicId":381                     
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ],
           "Topics":[
              {
                 "TopicId":371               
              },
              {
                 "TopicId":372
              },
              {
                 "TopicId":373
              }
           ]
        },      
        {
           "ModuleId":389,
           "Title":"Build Your Solution",
           "Modules":[
              {
                 "ModuleId":390,
                 "Title":"Core Platform Configuration",
                 "Modules":[
                    {
                       "ModuleId":392,
                       "Title":"Artifacts",                  
                       "Topics":[
                          {
                             "TopicId":393                          
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 ],
                 "Topics":[
                    {
                       "TopicId":391                   
                    }
                 ]
              }    

           ]
        }
     ]
  }
```

I convert it to a JObject and get all of the TopicIds using the following code.

```
var topicIds = jo.Descendants()
    .OfType<JProperty>()
    .Where(p => p.Name == "TopicId" &&
                p.Value != null)
    .ToList();
```

From there I need the TopicId's parent's ModuleId value.

I've tried the following but it returns all of the children of the parent.

```
foreach (var topicId in topicIds)
{

   var moduleId = jo.DescendantsAndSelf()
        .OfType<JProperty>()
        .Where(p => p.Value == topicId.Value)
        .Select(p => p.Parent)
        .ToString();
}
```

I just want the "ModuleId" value from the "TopicId" parent

Comment: what is the output you're expecting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the `topicId` property, so just navigate upward from there inside your loop to get the corresponding `moduleId` value:

```
var moduleId = (string)topicId.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent["ModuleId"];
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gOkKHt